# Visual Studio Uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, uninstallation, error-log

I am trying to simply uninstall and remove Visual Studio from my computer however when I go to control panel and find it to remove it the installer opens and I click remove then it gives me this error log. If anyone knows how to fix these issues help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

```
[2b18:000c][2019-02-21T17:20:25] Error 0x80131509: No product was found
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.GetRegisteredProduct()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Uninstall(CancellationToken token)
```

Update another error message gives this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the cleanup steps to remove VS 2017:

See if you have this file on your machine: "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe"

If so, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a -full param
**InstallCleanup.exe -full**

If not, please manually delete the "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer” folder

Relaunch the newly downloaded vs_enterprise.exe (or vs_professional.exe or vs_community.exe…)

Allow the first step to install the installer

Once the installer comes up and you can see workload choices (.net desktop and the like), close it

Go launch the same InstallCleanup.exe to clean up old build of VS